# Allocation quantity in SQL C#

Tags: sql

I have a problem, expect help, or ideas or any search keywords that can help me find a solution to the following problem:
I have 2 tables, 1 contains import information, 1 contains export information.

```
tblImport (iCode, ComponentCode, iTotal)
tblExport (eCode, ProductCode, ComponentCode, eNum)
```

[Idie allocation quantity two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu4TG.png)

Requirements: I have to create a table containing the eCode that has the eNum of each componentCode
that when sum(eNum) = iTotal. (Please see pictures)

Column 3 is the result I want, in that column (5) = iTotal - (sum (eNum) over (partition by iCode, eCode)). The condition is that each set (iCode, eCode, ComponentCode) only appears once. It means that the lines I have allocated will be ignored.
The problem here is that if  tblImport join tblExport via ComponentCode then this will not be true, there will be duplicate lines.

Can I implement this in SQL? If so please let me know technically possible to do that.
If none, please point me to how I can implement it either in SQL, or in C #.
Translate from Google Translator
 Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I did it !

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    ([OrderID] int, [Item] varchar(3), [Quantity] int)
;

INSERT INTO Orders
    ([OrderID], [Item], [Quantity])
VALUES
    (1, 'pen', 80),
    (2, 'pen', 30),
    (3, 'pen', 25)
;

CREATE TABLE Inventory
    ([InvID] int, [Lot] varchar(3), [Item] varchar(3), [Quantity] int)
;

INSERT INTO Inventory
    ([InvID], [Lot], [Item], [Quantity])
VALUES
    (1, '001', 'pen', 100),
    (2, '002', 'pen', 20),
    (3, '003', 'pen', 30)
;



INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory  VALUES  ( 4, '001','Ink',50 )
INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory  VALUES  ( 5, '002','Ink',50 )
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (4, 'Ink', 30)
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (5, 'Ink', 60)



    WITH CTE_Orders AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY OrderID) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Orders
)
, CTE_Inventory AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY InvID) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Inventory
)
, CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  o.RN AS OrderRN,
            inv.RN AS InvRN,
            OrderID ,
            o.Item ,
            o.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity ,
            InvID ,
            Lot ,
            inv.Quantity AS InvQuantity,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN o.Quantity  ELSE inv.Quantity END AS ServedQuantity ,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN 0 ELSE o.Quantity - inv.Quantity END AS LeftToServe,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity ELSE 0 END AS LeftInLot
    FROM CTE_Orders o
    INNER JOIN CTE_Inventory inv ON o.Item = inv.Item
    --WHERE OrderID = 1 AND InvID = 1
    WHERE o.RN =1 AND inv.RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderRN ELSE c2.OrderRN END AS OrderRN
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvRN ELSE c1.InvRN END AS InvRN
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderID ELSE c2.OrderID END AS OrderID
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.Item ELSE c2.Item END AS Item
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderedQuantity ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END AS OrderedQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvID ELSE c1.InvID END AS InvID
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.Lot ELSE c1.Lot END AS Lot
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END AS InvQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END
                  ELSE CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END
             END AS ServedQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END  
             END AS LeftToServe
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN  CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS LeftInLot
    FROM CTE c1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  o2.RN AS OrderRN,
                inv2.RN AS InvRN,
                InvID ,
                Lot ,
                inv2.Item ,
                inv2.Quantity AS InvQuantity,
                OrderID ,
                o2.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity
        FROM 
        CTE_Inventory inv2 
        INNER JOIN CTE_Orders o2 ON inv2.Item = o2.Item
    ) c2
    ON c1.Item = c2.Item AND
    ((c2.InvRN = c1.InvRN + 1 AND c2.OrderRN = c1.OrderRN AND c1.LeftInLot <= 0 ) OR (c2.OrderRN = c1.OrderRN + 1 AND c2.InvRN = c1.InvRN AND c1.LeftInLot>0))

)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY item,OrderID
```

It work !

Tks !

Comment: This is not a useful answer to anyone visiting the site later - it doesn't give *any* information beyond just a link. Please show the code *in your answer*, and add useful explanations. I'd also remove the C# tag, as there's no aspect of this which is really to do with C#.

Comment: Um, why not? It should be absolutely fine.